# List View Threshold and Managed Metadata fields with multiple values

Tags: 2010, document-library, web-application, list-view-threshold

We have a large document library with more than 25.000 files in it. 
All files have set `managed metadata` properties (multiple values allowed!) and some other fields for filtering this list and to get the needed documents.

This works fine, if I increase the `List View Threshold` in the WebApplication. Actually is set to 30.000, which is NOT recommended. We would like to set the `List View Threshold` back to the standard value = 5000.

If I do this, the list is loaded correctly.

If I filter the list with NON-`managed metadata` fields, all works fine.

BUT: When I filter the list on a `managed metadata` field it throws the error, that the `List view threshold` is exceeded:

> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view
>   threshold enforced by the
>   administrator.0x80070024

How can I reduce the value without running into this error? 
Does anybody have a hint?

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs most probably because you don't have index set on the Managed Metadata column (and you have it for other columns). First Increase the list view threshold (without increasing the threshold the index will not be created as that operation exceeds the list view threshold) , then go to to the library settings and under the columns list you will have link to the 'indexed columns' create index for the Managed Metadata column you want to filter. Then you can lower list view threshold back to 5K. Please note that creating indices for multiple columns actually reduces the performance of the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as far as I know to create an index on multiple managed metadata is impossible, isn't it? Actually there is no index set. On other columns filtering works fine.

Comment: Yep you are correct you cannot have index on the multi value metadata column (if I remember correctly same thing is for the choice column).

Comment: Then, is there any solution to this problem? I'm wondering, that Microsoft makes this topic so difficult.

Comment: Not out of the box. My approach to large lists is to ditch the list view web parts completely. In most cases I switch to the to the Search based solutions. Crawl the content of the list and use search to manage it. With SP2013 it is easier as some of the search web parts are provided out of the box but with SP2010 you will need to so some custom coding, with some work you can make it look like list view webPart but instead of querying the list directly it needs to use the search index (there is issue of the freshness so for frequently updated list it may be a problem)